# How to change the database error page to custom error page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the page showing when there is a database error. However I would like to not show it, what I like is a custom error page. How can I change it?

[image: Database error page]

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder  `application/views/errors/cli`.There a lots of error pages such as:

```
-error_404.php
-error_db.php
-error_exception.php
.. so on
```

Overide these pages to customize.